# Apply macro filter across Multiple worksheet in a workbook and and save the filtered value as another workbook containing those multiple sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook containing 23 work sheets. I have to apply Macro auto-filter to filter required data from the 23 work sheets and save those data as a work book with filtered data in those 23 work sheets..

```
     Sub Switch_Filter()
     Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, k1 As Integer
     Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
     Dim s As Variant, s1 As Variant


     j = Worksheets.Count


     s = InputBox("Enter Switch id")
     s1 = s & "*"
     If s <> vbNullString Then

     For k = 1 To 20
     If (k <> 1) And (k <> 4) And (k <> 7) Then
     With Worksheets(k)
     .UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=s1


     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     For i = 3 To LastRow


     Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 36)).Select
     Selection.Copy
     Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\takyar\Documents\salesmaster-new.xlsx"
     Worksheets(k).Select
     erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

     ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     ActiveWorkbook.Save
     ActiveWorkbook.Close
     Application.CutCopyMode = False


     Next i

     End With

     End If
     Next k
     End If
     End Sub
```

Almost Completed, but it save's the filtered data in the same sheet of the new workbook,here i have attached the code:-

```
     Sub Switch_Filter()
     Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
     Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
     Dim s As Variant, s1 As Variant
     Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook, newWork As Workbook
     Set MyWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

     j = Worksheets.Count

     s = InputBox("Enter Switch id")
     s1 = s & "*"
     If s <> vbNullString Then

     For k = 1 To 20

     With Worksheets(k)
     Set MyWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
     If (k <> 1) And (k <> 4) And (k <> 7) Then

    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Worksheets(k).UsedRange
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=s1
         End With
    End If

    MyWorkbook.Sheets(k).Rows("1:65000").Copy

    Set newWork = Workbooks.Open("E:\spreed sheet\sample1.xlsx")
    With newWork.Worksheets(k)
        Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

        newWork.Close

    End With

    End With
    Next k
    End If
    End Sub
```

pls suggest me a solution.

Thanks in Advance....!!!

Comment: `I have to apply Macro ...` So what is stopping you?

Comment: Mr Siddharth Rout, i don't known the exact way to code the macro

Comment: Do you know how to code in VBA?

Comment: yes little bit, is it possible to implement the mentioned concept???

Comment: Yes it is but I doubt anyone will give you the code in a platter (unless someone is looking to make some quick points). You will have to write your own code and then post the code here mentioning where exactly are you stuck.

Comment: just a minute i update my code

Comment: Mr Siddharth is it possible to apply auto filter from 5 row in excel

Answer (score 0):

Not even sure if this is executing, you didn't really say where your error is occurring.

Without that information, I think the biggest problem is that you are copying one row at a time and you are opening and closing a workbook every time you want to copy that row.

If you want the new workbook to contain all separate sheets just with the filtered data then you might want to consider creating a new worksheet within the old document with just the filtered data and cutting/moving it to the new document a whole sheet at a time. - That is something that you could learn the code from recording a macro and manually doing it.

Otherwise, if you can store this data all in 1 sheet/table I'd recommend loading each worksheet with its filtered data into one single array and then opening the new workbook and writing all of the information from that array. This option would most likely be the quickest.

Comment: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

error at this line Mr.Archias

Comment: sir is it possible to apply auto filter from the 5th row in a worksheet, because table headers starts from the 5th row 1ly

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got the Answer

```
      Sub Switch_Filter()
 Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
 Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
 Dim s As Variant, s1 As Variant
 Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook, newWork As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet

 Dim name As String



 Set MyWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

 j = Worksheets.Count

 s = InputBox("Enter Switch id")
 s1 = s & "*"
 If s <> vbNullString Then

 For k = 1 To j

 With Worksheets(k)

 Set MyWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
 '.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=s1
    If (k <> 1) And (k <> 4) And (k <> 7) And (k < 20) Then

    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Worksheets(k).UsedRange
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=s1
         End With
    End If
 'LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    MyWorkbook.Sheets(k).Rows("1:65000").Copy

    Set newWork = Workbooks.Open("E:\spreed sheet\sample1.xlsx")


    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    name = ws.name

    With newWork.Sheets(name)

        Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

        newWork.Close

    End With

 End With
 Next k
 End If
 End Sub
```